# Spreadsheet.open in Rails gives this error "unknown encoding name - MACINTOSH"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, spreadsheet, xls

I am using Spreadsheet to parse xls files. It's working great. but today one of my user has uploaded a file and it's getting an error "unknown encoding name - MACINTOSH"

My code is: 
book = Spreadsheet.open file_path
sheet1 = book.worksheet 0

This is the excel file which is getting the error: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jv37pk5rpiy9259/testlisttextnonames2.xls

Can you guys please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I'm getting this same error on a simple Ruby script and found this question on Google. Hopefully someone can answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same problem. Here is the best i can deduce:

"Macintosh" is not a known encoding in Ruby 1.9+. Try opening a console and running "Encoding.find('Macintosh')". You'll get the same error.

So what is available? In the console: "Encoding.list". One of the options is MacRoman. I'm guessing this is a close second.

So if we change the mapping in lib/spreadsheet/excel/internals.rb for 10000 and 32768 to map to "MACROMAN", it should work.

Tested locally and it does.

I opened a pull request: https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/pull/51

Some reference links:
 * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman
 * http://bugs.python.org/issue843590